# Let $F$ and $K$ be fields. If $F\subseteq K$ and $r\in K$ s.t. $r^2$ is algebraic over $F$. Then $r$ is algebraic over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ and $K$ be fields. If $F\subseteq K$ and $r\in K$ s.t. $r^2$ is algebraic over $F$. Then $r$ is algebraic over $F$.

Assume polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ s.t. $p(r^2)=0$

If $r\in K$ and $r^2$ is algebraic over $F$ I'm looking for a polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ s.t. $p(r)=0$? Or, does it not have to be the same polynomial? How do I know if I'm to use the same polynomial for $r$ and $r^2$, or different ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left(\left(\sqrt[4]{2}\right)^2\right)^2-2=0\Rightarrow (\sqrt[4]{2})^4-2=0$

Comment: I may be missing something. Is this more than just a concrete example?

Comment: yes.. i actually said more than what i am supposed to...

Comment: @GiGi You can use this concrete example as inspiration for the general case.

Comment: Hmm. Let's see here...

Comment: you still have some difficulty?

Comment: I hit enter a few times before I was done typing so the beginning of what I had may have popped up a few times. I was on my way to finding a generalization but now I'm getting stuck.

Comment: See, i have $r^2=(\sqrt[4]{2})^2=\sqrt{2}$ and for this i have minimal polynomial $x^2-2$ and for $r=\sqrt[4]{2}$ i have minimal polynomial $x^4-2$.... Can you now see what i am doing?

Comment: We've generalized it such that for any $r^2$ that is algebraic $r$ will be algebraic with $x^{2k}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;r^2\;$ be a zero of $\;f(x)\in F[x]\;$ :

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k\implies 0=f(r^2)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k(r^2)^k=\sum_{k=0}^na_kr^{2k}$$